# Opening File in C++ - getline fails on second iteration

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io

I cannot figure out why getline is working in one X-Code project but not in another. The error "No matching function for call to 'getline'.
When I make a single cpp file it compiles with no issues.

```
  // reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
      string line;
      ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
      if (myfile.is_open())
      {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
          getline (myfile,line);
          cout << line << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
      }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate some assistance. I am just learning and the example above came from my test book.

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: If you figure out what you are trying to ask, could you make the title of the question reflect that? Currently it is quite confusing.

Comment: That code looks like a single cpp file. Is this the file you're having problems with or the one that compiles? (The title of this question has nothing to do with compilation.)

Comment: Rereading this after a year and change, it just shows are the arrogance of some programmers to those learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is noisy and incorrect. The correct standard idiom is like this:

```
#include <fstream>   // for std::ifstream
#include <string>    // for std::getline and std::string

std::ifstream myfile("example.txt");

if (!myfile) { /* error, die */ }

for (std::string line; std::getline(myfile, line); )
{
    std::cout << "Read one line: '" << line << "'\n";
}
```

**Correctness:**

- You must check the success of the input operation *before* consuming the input. To do otherwise may be UB, and certainly never correct.
- [Thanks @James for pointing this out:] `good()` doesn't check if a file was opened. You could use either `!myfile.fail()` or `myfile.is_open()`, but just don't bother (see below).

**Noise:**

- The `ifstream` constructor takes the filename and opens the file already. Use it.
- The `ifstream` cleans up in its destructor, no need to do that explicitly. Use tight scoping to close the file as soon as you're done with it.
- Don't leak `line` into the ambient scope if you don't need it.
- No need for `good()` (or any of the correct alternatives). Just evaluate the `ifstream` object in a boolean context to see if the file was opened successfully.

Comment: You could argue both ways for most of these suggestiongs, but the use of `good()` in the original is just incorrect.  (I would, for example, use a `while` rather than a `for` here, with the variable declared outside of the loop.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Good point about `good()`, I added that -- thanks!

Comment: Like many people, I prefer `myfile.is_open()` to just `myfile` to test if the open succeeded.  It's more explicit.  And I wouldn't use a `for` here; it doesn't seem to correspond to what _I_ expect in a `for`.  (But when to choose `for`, and when to choose `while`, is about on the same level as where to put the braces.  With perhaps even more "correct" solutions.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Hehe, well, on my part I'm slowly coming to the conclusion that basically *every* loop is a `for` loop, and best written as such. I'm still working on that hypothesis, though, but I've got a good amount of supporting cases already. (Though I recently learned that the designers of Go seem to agree :-).)

Comment: Part of my confusion on this issue, does this check if the file exists or does it check if the system can open it. Or both. May sound simple but not for me. In my case,and the code at top would simple create the file if it did not exist.

Comment: @diek: `ifstream` doesn't create files. If the file cannot be opened, this code will tell you. There's no way to distinguish the in the standard library between a non-existing file and a file for which you don't have sufficient permissions, since the standard library doesn't know about file *systems*. You need a platform-specific library for that in any case (or Boost.Filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

There is one actual error: you use the results of `getline`
without testing whether it has succeeded.  The usual way of
writing your inner loop would be:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( myfile, line ) ) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Others are more question of style, although some issues do
enjoy almost universal consensus: don't define a variable
before you need it, for example (and thus, the definition of
`line` should be immediately before the loop).  Error output
goes to `std::cerr`, not `std::out.  And in case of an error,
you should return`EXIT_FAILURE`, and not`0`.

It's also generally accepted that you don't have to explicitly
close input (since the destructor will take care of it, and
you've already successfully read everything).  The consensus
isn't as complete for others: I would never use `using namespace
std;`, for example, and I would never put the code following an
`else` on the same line.  I also find code more readable if the
shorter condition in an `if...else` is the first, so I'd write:

```
if ( !myfile.is_open() ) {
    std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl
    returnCode = EXIT_FAILURE;
} else {
    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline( myfile, line ) ) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    returnCode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Except that for anything more complicated, I'd factor the
processing of the file out into a separate function.  So I'd end
up with something like:

```
if ( myfile.is_open() ) {
    process( myfile );
} else {
    //  error handling...
}
```

But you seem to suggest that you're having problems with
`std::getline` in code you don't post.  There are two obvious
possible explinations: you didn't include `<string>`, or you
forgot the `std::` in front of it.  There are other possible
explinations, but we'd have to actually see the code which is
failing to say exactly what is wrong.

Comment: James, Thank you. I am obviously learning C++ and one issue that I have these days is google search. Search results are dominated by forum questions and with a mariad of answers that go from correct to messy. The example at top comes straight from cplusplus often cited as a very good resource.

Comment: @diek I just had a look at the two tutorial pages concerning IO at the cplusplus site, and both are very bad, and filled with errors.  The author obviously doesn't know how to do IO in C++.  I would avoid this site.

Comment: James, your going that extra bit to help me out by looking deeper into this one. Trust me I appreciate it. This is part of a project for school. Adam Drozdek's Line Editor problem from his Data Structure and Algorithms in C++. The actual problem was using linked lists but I found that part easy, and the general mechanics harder.